# Formatting Question with Equation

Tags: equations

I'm writing my homework solutions in TeX and I'm trying to write out this question:

[image]

Here's what I have so far,

```
Consider the following two IVPs:\\

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{gather}
\text{(i)}\nonumber\\
y'=xy\nonumber\\
y(0)=1
\end{gather}

Estimate $y(1)$.
```

There are a couple of things I'm off by,

1. The '(i)' is completely off
2. How do I get the equation citation in the middle of the two equations?
3. How do I align the equal signs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\\` after IVPS: is wrong: never end a paragraph with `\\` it always warns in the log about that and makes terrible output.

To align equals  use `align` not `gather` and then use `&=` to mark the alignment point. Or if you want to consider the pair as a single numberd equation then

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y'&=xy\\
y(0)&=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

The `\text{(i)}` should be outside the mathematics presumably it should be `\item` marking the first term of a nested `enumerate` but hard to tell from the fragment posted.

Comment: And yes, \enumerate\item{(i)} is perfect as well, thank you

Comment: @TheMonkey no! `\begin{enumerate}` not `\enumerate` and `\item` not `\item[(i)]` try to avoid manual numbering wherever possible, you can specify elsewhere you want enumerations to use roman numbers.